# PhaseScriptExecution failed and CompileSwiftSources failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, react-native

**Objective**

I am trying to build my project to an iOS simulator or physical device using Xcode.

**System and software details**

macOS Monterey
Version 12.2.1

Macbook Pro (2021)

Chip: Apple M1 Pro

Memory: 16GB

XCode 13.0

Node version: 16.14.2

npm version: 8.5.0

**Problem**

On opening my project in Xcode, this message is displayed:
[Xcode message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbO5L.png)

Running build fails with:

*Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code*

and

*remark: Incremental compilation has been disabled: it is not compatible with whole module optimization
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code*

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jp6N.png)

[PhaseScriptExecution error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn9js.png)

[CompileSwiftSources error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maWsD.png)

**What we've tried**

I've tried a lot of solutions online but no luck
Solutions tried are:

- Build Settings -> Compilation Mode -> Switch to "Incremental" (This didnt help because the setting was already on "Incremental")
- Excluding arm64 architecture in build settings
- Changing swift version in build settings

I've tried Xcode 13.0, 13.2, 13.2.1, 13.3, 12.5

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Please tell me if any other information is needed

Comment: The error message presents a possible solution; get an older version of XCode to open the project (will require an older Mac). That process will update it to a newer version which can then be opened with a current version of XCode. Another option is to create a new XCode project and then open the individual, really old and freezer burned ( @matt lol! ) files from your original project and copy and paste the code into new files. You *may* be able to even drag and drop them from the desktop into the new XCode project. Keep in mind that your old Swift code may not work and will require re-writes.

Comment: @Jay "get an older version of XCode to open the project" And run it how? This is an M1. It won't run an older Xcode.

Comment: @Matt --> *(will require an older Mac)*. And you can use Parallels (or another VM) to run and older macOS on M1 - we do it all the time.

Comment: @Jay But that violates the conditions of the question. If this project were still sitting on the very old computer with the very old Xcode that created it, this question would not exist. But evidently it isn't. Anyway, this now devolves into a hardware or general software matter. There's no programming here. The question belongs on another site.

Comment: @Matt - the only condition I see is this *Does anyone have a solution to this?*. Getting or using an old Mac with and older XCode and/or running a VM with an older OS satisfies that ask - but it's not really an *answer* which is why I didn't post it as such. I am presenting possible options for the OP, just trying to help :-)